# biblatex - a problem with cyrillic 'О' in \cite

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have no ideas about this.
Look at minimal example.

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage [
            style       = gost-numeric,
            backend     = biber,
            language    = auto
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[{АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ О}~1234567890]{A}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`ref.bib`:

```
@ARTICLE{A,
    author      = {author},
    title       = {title},
    journal     = {journal},
    year        = {2000},
    volume      = {1},
    pages       = {1--100}
}
```

Output:

```
Errors:

.../minimal.tex:18: Missing ) inserted for expression. [...ХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ О}~1234567890]{A}.]
.../minimal.tex:18: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [...ХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ О}~1234567890]{A}.]
.../minimal.tex:18: Missing number, treated as zero. [...ХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ О}~1234567890]{A}.]
.../minimal.tex:18: Missing ) inserted for expression. [...ХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ О}~1234567890]{A}.]
.../minimal.tex:18: Missing number, treated as zero. [...ХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ О}~1234567890]{A}.]
.../minimal.tex:18: Missing ) inserted for expression. [...ХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ О}~1234567890]{A}.]
.../minimal.tex:18: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [...ХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ О}~1234567890]{A}.]
.../minimal.tex:18: Missing number, treated as zero. [...ХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ О}~1234567890]{A}.]
.../minimal.tex:18: Missing ) inserted for expression. [...ХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ О}~1234567890]{A}.]
.../minimal.tex:18: Missing = inserted for \ifnum. [...ХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ О}~1234567890]{A}.]
.../minimal.tex:18: Missing number, treated as zero. [...ХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ О}~1234567890]{A}.]
```

There is full Russian alphabet, but only 'О' gives a problem. Deleting the 'О' gives 'No errors'.

Does anybody know what's the trouble?

Comment: Probably intputenc - it doesn't cover the full range of UTF8.

Comment: It seems that `\ifnumeral` chokes with the Cyrillic O

Comment: @PLK I see `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{041E}{\CYRO}` in `t2aenc.dfu`

Comment: @PLK The error appears with `\blx@imc@ifnumeral{О}{true}{false}`

Comment: See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/559

Comment: @egreg, is it possibble to fix it in my paper?

Comment: @Dmitry Use `\CYRO` instead of the Cyrillic O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a bug in `\blx@imc@ifnumeral`, because the behavior can be reproduced with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
%\blx@imc@ifnumeral{Н}{\typeout{numeral}}{\typeout{not numeral}}
\blx@imc@ifnumeral{О}{\typeout{numeral}}{\typeout{not numeral}}
%\blx@imc@ifnumeral{П}{\typeout{numeral}}{\typeout{not numeral}}
%\blx@imc@ifnumeral{н}{\typeout{numeral}}{\typeout{not numeral}}
%\blx@imc@ifnumeral{о}{\typeout{numeral}}{\typeout{not numeral}}
%\blx@imc@ifnumeral{п}{\typeout{numeral}}{\typeout{not numeral}}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

The commented lines will not trigger the error. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/559 for a report.

You can “fix” the issue with a kludge: use

```
\CYRO
```

instead of the Cyrillic `О` (U+041E CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER O).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{A,
    author      = {author},
    title       = {title},
    journal     = {journal},
    year        = {2000},
    volume      = {1},
    pages       = {1--100}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage [
            style       = gost-numeric,
            backend     = biber,
            language    = auto
            ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНП\CYRO РСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ~1234567890]{A}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]